# java.lang.IllegalAccessError while trying to test a jersey REST webservice deployed on TomEE

Tags: apache, jersey, apache-tomee

I have a Jersey-based REST webservice which is working fine when deployed on Glassfish. When I deploy the same war file on Apache TomEE+ 1.6 version, i get the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getContextClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader; from class com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener
com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.&lt;init&gt;(AnnotationScannerListener.java:89)
com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.PathProviderScannerListener.&lt;init&gt;(PathProviderScannerListener.java:59)
com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.&lt;init&gt;(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.&lt;init&gt;(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried using WebProfile and JAX RS version of TomEE also, but same issue.

My pom.xml dependencies look like this:

```
<dependencies>


        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.api</groupId>
                <artifactId>api</artifactId>
                <version>1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>core</artifactId>
                <version>10.0-b28</version>
                <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>

        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-alpha-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

                 <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                 </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>asm</groupId>
                <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                <version>20041228.180559</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.1</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-tomee</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

Has anyone faced this before? Please help.

Comment: I've stumbled upon the same issue, but on Glassfish. My code was working perfectly before, now it's not. I have no idea what changed... Have you figured it out somehow ?

Comment: facing the same issue.Any solution?

Answer (score 3):

I added jersey-bundle-1.8-ea03.jar from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle/1.8-ea03) and this error was solved.

Comment: Although it is useful; looks its not exact answer. It should go in as a comment.

Comment: if your answer is useful then please provide more information about that jar file. Thus, you can make your answer more informative for other user also otherwise users can give the flag for `it is not an Answer`.  thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Noticed, that this happens if the dependencies are inconsistent... I updated jersey dependencies.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with this dependency and its working on **apache-tomcat-7.0.69**

```
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

[image]