# Restful WebApp working on glassfish but not tomcat

Tags: rest, tomcat, glassfish, jersey

I've developed a webApp in netbeans, supposed to serve my Android app.
I'm new to hosting a webApp, i've rented a VPS. Will i need to install glassfish on it? if yes, could you provide me with some resource ( Tutorial, or something like that ) on how to do that ( I use cPanel,on the VPS side );if no, same, i need some tutorial on how to deploy it on cPanel.

In netbeans,It runs successfully on glassfish but when ran on tomcat, it gives the foollowing error:

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getContextClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader; from class com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener
at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.<init>(AnnotationScannerListener.java:89)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.PathProviderScannerListener.<init>(PathProviderScannerListener.java:59)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5266)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5554)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:677)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1912)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Jun 04, 2015 2:02:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [ServletAdaptor] in web application [/monWenze] threw load() exception
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getContextClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader; from class com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener
at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.<init>(AnnotationScannerListener.java:89)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.PathProviderScannerListener.<init>(PathProviderScannerListener.java:59)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5266)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5554)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:677)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1912)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Jun 04, 2015 2:02:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Jun 04, 2015 2:02:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Jun 04, 2015 2:02:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@1bb9d54')
Jun 04, 2015 2:03:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getContextClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader; from class com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener
at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.<init>(AnnotationScannerListener.java:89)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.PathProviderScannerListener.<init>(PathProviderScannerListener.java:59)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5266)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5554)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:4033)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.reload(ManagerServlet.java:1012)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:381)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Jun 04, 2015 2:03:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [ServletAdaptor] in web application [/monWenze] threw load() exception
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getContextClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader; from class com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener
at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.<init>(AnnotationScannerListener.java:89)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.PathProviderScannerListener.<init>(PathProviderScannerListener.java:59)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5266)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5554)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:4033)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.reload(ManagerServlet.java:1012)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:381)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: It seems your dependencies were (maybe partially) provided by Glassfish. Try with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560345/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-while-trying-to-test-a-jersey-rest-webservice-deplo).

Comment: francesco foresti 6, I'm not using maven...

Comment: ok, so you'll have to package the dependencies by hand (or with your IDE's tools). Try to put all the required Jersey JARs in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your application, and then redeploy it in Tomcat.