# Deploying war on linux

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, jersey

Hello I downloaded tomcat 8.5.4 when and I ve made some simple rest aplication with jersey. When I deploy war on tomcat on windows it works fine. When i copied whole directory to linux server(downloaded version is multiplatform) and I deploy application, Linux dont see my Rest Controller. 
Same files of server, same war and windows working, linux not...

output from windows:

```
21-Aug-2016 19:12:52.370 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.test.rest
21-Aug-2016 19:12:52.414 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.logClasses Root resource classes found:
  class com.test.rest.RestController
21-Aug-2016 19:12:52.414 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init No provider classes found.
21-Aug-2016 19:12:52.568 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.18 11/22/2013 03:05 AM'
21-Aug-2016 19:12:53.773 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive D:\tomcat-8.5.4\webapps\RestServices.war has finished in 2,654 ms
```

output from linux

```
21-Aug-2016 19:17:01.343 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.test.rest
21-Aug-2016 19:17:01.398 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /home/tomcat-8.5.4/webapps/RestServices.war has fished in 3,342 ms
```

and when I call rests:

```
Servlet.init() for servlet jersey-serlvet threw exception
...
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getContextClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader; from class com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you test on the Windows box also? I mean, hitting a REST end-point?

Comment: Yep it works fine. I even took my local ip(192...) and tried with that. Because I locally have windows, linux is remote server. I belive that is some problem with encoding or smth like that ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look here if any of the answers might cover your problem?

[java.lang.IllegalAccessError while trying to test a jersey REST webservice deployed on TomEE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560345/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-while-trying-to-test-a-jersey-rest-webservice-deplo)

Comment: thx I coppied dependencies from post from your link and it worked... -.-