# Jersey error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, jersey

My Node.JS API (localhost) call a Jersey API on the Tomcat server (localhost) worked really well previously, but I don't know why it accidentally failed today. I have checked that all files have not modified since last week. Once I tried to GET http://localhost:8080/graybox/rest/analytic

It will fail and show these message in the eclipse console.

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [Jersey Web Application]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:544)
    ...
```

I have surveyed a lot but I still can't find a way to solve my problem. The following is what I have done previously try to resolve this issue, which also attaches dev environment, web.xml and pom.xml. Thanks.

1. Install maven (brew), m2eclipse (Eclipse install new software), m2e-wtp (Eclipse install new software) Eclipse install new software: Help -> Install New Software -> copy paste the url into "Work with" -> Choose all and Next and Finish [m2eclipse](https://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/)[m2e-wtp](http://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/releases/neon/)
2. Eclipse: Import -> Existing Maven project -> choose "graybox" project folder
3. Rebuild Maven global index in Eclipse: [Detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164893/how-do-i-add-a-maven-dependency-in-eclipse)
4. Add dependencies in Maven to make sure all jersey dependencies in the same version e.g. all 1.19 version jersey-server, jersey-bundle, jersey-core, jersey-json [Reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560345/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-while-trying-to-test-a-jersey-rest-webservice-deplo)
5. Clean Maven dependencies

   1. Project -> Clean -> Clean
   2. Right click project -> Maven -> Update Project
   3. Right click project -> Run as -> 4 (or 5) Maven build -> Goals: clean install -> Apply -> Run [Detail](https://crunchify.com/mavenmvn-clean-install-update-project-and-project-clean-options-in-eclipse-ide-to-fix-any-dependency-issue/)
6. If there are more than one Tomcat servers running, remove unrelated Tomcat servers, make sure choose the right one in runtime: Window -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environments -> Remove all unrelated servers
7. Add server Tomcat [Detail](https://crunchify.com/step-by-step-guide-to-setup-and-install-apache-tomcat-server-in-eclipse-development-environment-ide/) Before running the server, double-click the server -> Server Locations: Use Tomcat installation … [Detail](https://web.archive.org/web/20180814215758/http://code2care.org:80/2015/error-404-tomcat-homepage-http:localhost:8080-not-displayed/)
8. Right click project -> Properties -> Project facets -> Choose: Dynamic Web Module, Java, JavaScript, JAX-RS (REST Web Services) -> Runtimes -> Choose the right server -> Apply -> Apply and Choose
9. Start server -> Run project -> browser http://localhost:8080/ -> show welcome page of Tomcat

Environment

- Mac os x 10.13.2, x86_64
- Eclipse Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
- Back-end

  - Java jdk1.8.0_151-b12

    - Tomcat 8.5
    - Maven 3.5.2
      Default locale: en_AU, platform encoding: UTF-8
    - Jersey 1.19
  - Node 8.9.4

    - NPM 5.6.0
    - Bower 1.8.2
    - Nodemon 1.14.11

This is web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
    <display-name>Graybox</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>graybox</groupId>
  <artifactId>graybox</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <finalName>graybox</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
      <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
      <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>asm</groupId>
      <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
      <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20170516</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
      <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086218/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-jersey-spi-container-servlet-servletco

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086218/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-jersey-spi-container-servlet-servletco)

Comment: Thank both of you. You are correct. I am not sure why Eclipse doesn't save Maven in Java Build Path Entries when I turn off the Eclipse. Thank you for saving my day!

Comment: check solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70641059/5357845

Answer (score 0):

Due to accidentally shut down my Eclipse, it seems that the Java Build Path doesn't save Maven. It is the same as one of the answers answered by Adi

[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086218/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-jersey-spi-container-servlet-servletco)

Right click your eclipse project Properties -> Deployment Assembly -> Add -> Java Build Path Entries -> Gradle Dependencies -> Finish.